# PKG installer seems signed correctly, but still saying "unidentified developer" on Catalina

Tags: macos, code-signing, macos-catalina, pkgbuild, pkg-file

we code-sign all executables, the .app and then the final installer (pkg). It works on previous MacOS versions, but sadly, users on **MacOS Catalina** get the message that the package is from an **unidentified developer**. I tried to find what's going on and used *pkgutil* and *spctl* on Catalina. This is the result:

[image: Showing pkgutil result]

But sadly, Gatekeeper says he does not like it and rejects:

[image: spctl does not like and rejects the signature]

Any idea what might be wrong here? The certificate is good until 2022 and no errors during signing.

I don't want to tell users to right click and "open" the setup from Finder. I also do not want them to turn off Gatekeeper. This are workarounds only, but is there a chance to sign it the way it is accepted by MacOS Catalina? Or how to find out why it rejects it?

Comment: Did you also notarize?  Catalina requirement.

Comment: @RichardBarber I thought this is only needed for distribution through the app store? Is it also needed for manual distribution of .pkg files? Also, I thought this is optional?

Comment: Gatekeeper in *Catalina* is going to look for a "ticket" generated by Apple's "notarization" anti-malware scanner. Gatekeeper in *Catalina* works the same way whether App Store or outside distributed.

Comment: @RichardBarber Okay, thanks. I will try that...

Answer (score 3):

The reason was the missing notarization. After notarization, the issues were solved.